# cakephp isauthorized check inside other controller action

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, cakephp-1.3

let's say I have a function `isAuthorized()` in my controller that checks if a user has permission to execute the controller actions `add` and `edit`. Now let's say I'm inside a controller action `my_custom_action`. How do I check if my user has permission to execute the actions `add` and `edit` inside my controller action `my_custom_action` by using something like:

```
$this->Auth->isAuthorized();
```

Thank you

Comment: That depends on how your `isAuthorized` method is implemented. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve though? Maybe something like ACL or a similar "real" permission system is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In the app_controller I created this (kind of) function. First I check the Controller being used and then I check the action for the controller. You can also try looking at this '[Simple Model-Based Access Control](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/linnk/2009/03/24/simple-model-based-access-control)' bakery article.

```
function isAuthorized() {
    switch($this->name) {
        case 'Everyone': /* EveryoneController */
            return true;
            break;
        case 'Banned': /* BannedController */
            $this->Auth->authError = __('You do not have permission to ', true).$this->action.' '.strtolower($this->name);
            return false;
            break;
        default:
            switch($this->action) {
                case 'index':
                    return true;
                    break;
                case 'add':
                case 'edit':
                case 'delete':
                    if (/* permission check */) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        $this->Auth->authError = __('You do not have permission to ', true).$this->action.' '.strtolower($this->name);
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No this was for Cake 1.2, I doubt its changed much though

Comment: Oops, sorry didn't see the 1.3 tag on the question.

Comment: For those stumbling upon this: the outer switch here should be eliminated, the contents of each case moved to an isAuthorized() function in the appropriate controller, and the switch in the "default" case left as isAuthorized() in AppController.  That way any controller-specific isAuthorized() will be used, but if the controller doesn't have an isAuthorized() function, it will fall back to the AppController version.  This has the same effect as the above code, but is much better organized and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

This checks if current user requesting 'my_custom_action' is an admin, and if so grant access.

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {

        if (in_array($this->action, array('my_custom_action'))) {

             if ($this->Auth->user('is_admin')) 
                return true; 
             else 
                return false;
        }
}
```